# How to do a calculation in a column using another columns in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  sf_name       finish_position    official_rating       date          bsp       diff
Camanche Grey          11                 NULL         2013-09-18     72.53      0.00
Camanche Grey           4                 NULL         2013-11-08     12.50      0.00
Camanche Grey           3                 NULL         2014-02-27     24.00      0.00
Camanche Grey           6                  65          2014-04-24     32.00      0.00
Camanche Grey          13                  63          2014-05-05    109.06      0.00
Camanche Grey           1                  59          2014-07-04      4.16      0.00
Camanche Grey           2                  65          2014-08-04      5.10     -6.00
Camanche Grey          12                  68          2014-10-28     55.00     -9.00
Camanche Grey           9                  62          2014-12-09    110.89     -3.00
Camanche Grey           5                  65          2015-01-08     61.07     -6.00
Camanche Grey           7                  60          2015-01-29     12.54     -1.00
Camanche Grey          11                  65          2015-04-08     15.50     -6.00
Camanche Grey           5                  63          2015-04-22     36.07     -4.00
Camanche Grey           1                  60          2015-07-14      4.25      0.00
Camanche Grey           9                  60          2015-08-04      5.30      0.00
Camanche Grey           8                  56          2016-01-22     22.67      4.00
Camanche Grey           4                  52          2016-02-26     11.76      8.00
Camanche Grey           7                  50          2016-03-31      4.30     10.00
Camanche Grey           8                  48          2016-04-25      6.31     12.00
Camanche Grey           4                  56          2016-07-12      9.50      4.00
Camanche Grey           8                  47          2016-09-23     23.47     13.00
Camanche Grey           9                  52          2017-06-20    114.54      8.00
Camanche Grey           1                  50          2017-07-04     15.51      0.00
Camanche Grey           3                  55          2017-07-20      5.29     -5.00
Camanche Grey           3                  48          2017-07-29     15.51      2.00
Camanche Grey           2                  47          2017-08-24      8.00      3.00
Camanche Grey          10                  38          2018-01-12     17.70     12.00
Camanche Grey           2                  55          2018-07-19     27.28     -5.00
Camanche Grey           3                  54          2018-07-30      6.78     -4.00
Camanche Grey           1                  54          2018-08-21     24.00      0.00
```

I have a table. I want an output result with extra new column called "profit/loss".

Here are the conditions to make that column.

1. We need to find the first row that has finish_position is 1 (for this table it is in 6th row). So this row and above rows profit/loss is 0.00
2. We need to find the first row that has diff is 10 or greater than 10 (for this table it is in 18th row). Then we need to assign profit/loss is 10 for that row. Also above rows profit/loss is 0.00
3. Then each next rows profit/loss will increase by 10 until finish_position is 1 (for this table it is in 23rd row).
4. Finally we need to do a calculation in profit/loss column in 23rd row.

   ```
   Calculation Formula = (bsp for that row * 10) - (profit/loss for that row)
               example = (15.51 * 10) - (60)  
                       = 155.1 - 60
                       = 95.1
   ```

So in that 23rd row profit/loss column has 95.1 value. You guys can get a clear idea from below table.

```
   sf_name       finish_position    official_rating       date         bsp       diff     profit/loss
Camanche Grey          11                 NULL         2013-09-18     72.53      0.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           4                 NULL         2013-11-08     12.50      0.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           3                 NULL         2014-02-27     24.00      0.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           6                  65          2014-04-24     32.00      0.00         0.00
Camanche Grey          13                  63          2014-05-05    109.06      0.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           1                  59          2014-07-04      4.16      0.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           2                  65          2014-08-04      5.10     -6.00         0.00
Camanche Grey          12                  68          2014-10-28     55.00     -9.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           9                  62          2014-12-09    110.89     -3.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           5                  65          2015-01-08     61.07     -6.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           7                  60          2015-01-29     12.54     -1.00         0.00
Camanche Grey          11                  65          2015-04-08     15.50     -6.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           5                  63          2015-04-22     36.07     -4.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           1                  60          2015-07-14      4.25      0.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           9                  60          2015-08-04      5.30      0.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           8                  56          2016-01-22     22.67      4.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           4                  52          2016-02-26     11.76      8.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           7                  50          2016-03-31      4.30     10.00        10.00
Camanche Grey           8                  48          2016-04-25      6.31     12.00        20.00
Camanche Grey           4                  56          2016-07-12      9.50      4.00        30.00
Camanche Grey           8                  47          2016-09-23     23.47     13.00        40.00
Camanche Grey           9                  52          2017-06-20    114.54      8.00        50.00
Camanche Grey           1                  50          2017-07-04     15.51      0.00        95.51
Camanche Grey           3                  55          2017-07-20      5.29     -5.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           3                  48          2017-07-29     15.51      2.00         0.00
Camanche Grey           2                  47          2017-08-24      8.00      3.00         0.00
Camanche Grey          10                  38          2018-01-12     17.70     12.00        10.00
Camanche Grey           2                  55          2018-07-19     27.28     -5.00        20.00
Camanche Grey           3                  54          2018-07-30      6.78     -4.00        30.00
Camanche Grey           1                  54          2018-08-21     24.00      0.00       200.00
```

Another calculation happened from row 27th to row 30. Because 27th row diff is greater than 12.

Here is the fiddle link : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a100e032fcd811ab2dee093b20a97bd6

I tried a code. Please check and let me know...

Comment: I don't get the calculation at all.  There are values above 10 before the "18th" row.

Comment: We need to find the first diff value in the table that is equal to 10 or greater than 10.

Comment: So all columns are irrelevant to this problem except for finish_position, date, and diff?

Comment: We want bsp column for the calculation

Comment: yes. MySQL version 8.0.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT *, 
       @f1 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 0 AND finish_position = 1
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE @f1
                   END f1,
       @f2 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND diff >= 10
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE @f2
                   END f2,
       @f3 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND @f2 = 1
                   THEN @f3 + 10
                   ELSE 0
                   END f3,
       CASE WHEN @f3 > 0 AND finish_position = 1
                   THEN bsp * 10 - @f3
                   ELSE @f3
                   END `profit/loss`,
       CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND @f2 = 1 AND finish_position = 1
                   THEN (@f1 := 1) + (@f2 := 0) + (@f3 := 0)
                   ELSE 0
                   END f4
FROM test, ( SELECT @f1 := 0, @f2 := 0, @f3 := 0 ) vars
ORDER BY datec;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a07e866e30b5543dc98e2b4954893b04)

---

> I don't want to show "f" related columns in the output – Zajjith Vedha

Use this query as a subquery moving ordering to outer query.

```sql
SELECT sf_name, finish_position, official_rating, datec, bsp, diff, `profit/loss`
FROM (
SELECT *, 
       @f1 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 0 AND finish_position = 1
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE @f1
                   END f1,
       @f2 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND diff >= 10
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE @f2
                   END f2,
       @f3 := CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND @f2 = 1
                   THEN @f3 + 10
                   ELSE 0
                   END f3,
       CASE WHEN @f3 > 0 AND finish_position = 1
                   THEN bsp * 10 - @f3
                   ELSE @f3
                   END `profit/loss`,
       CASE WHEN @f1 = 1 AND @f2 = 1 AND finish_position = 1
                   THEN (@f1 := 1) + (@f2 := 0) + (@f3 := 0)
                   ELSE 0
                   END f4
FROM test, ( SELECT @f1 := 0, @f2 := 0, @f3 := 0 ) vars
) subquery
ORDER BY datec;
```

Comment: How can I only showing the output with sf_name, finish_position, official_rating, date, bsp, profit/loss columns?

Comment: I don't want to show "f" related columns in the output

Comment: @ZajjithVedha Use this query as a subquery moving ordering to outer query... updated.